# AFTER INSERT Trigger is executed only once after insert into (multiple insert)

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, procedure

I am writing a procedure in Sql Server which insert some rows into table x from table y
using the command `insert into`, something like

```
insert into x([column1],[column2]..) 
select column1, column2,..
from y
```

I have an `AFTER INSERT Trigger` for table x,
I expect the trigger to be called every time a new row is inserted into table x,
but actually, it's executed just once, even the `select` command after the `insert into`
command returns more than one row, my trigger:

```
alter trigger AddToYTrigger
on x
after insert
as
begin
     print 'trigger start'
     ....
end
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  You have explained the inaccuracy in your understanding of SQL Server triggers.

Comment: *"I expect the trigger to be called every time a new row is inserted into table x"* A trigger is called each time a DML statement is made, not for every row. [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: You need to include more of your trigger function so that we can assist you to convert it into a set-based statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment:

> I expect the trigger to be called every time a new row is inserted into table x

As you point out, this expectation is simply wrong.  That is why SQL Server provides the `inserted` view.  This contains the rows that are being inserted and it is intended to be used in the trigger.

A trigger that assumes that `inserted` has only one row is a bug.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not catch this bug, so you have to be careful with writing the trigger.